# How to programmatically change fragment layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait, orientation-changes

I have a camera fragment with a preview class that runs in a full screen mode. There is a noticeable pause when switching from portrait to landscape modes upon device rotation. I've forced the activity to operate in a portrait mode and now there are no more delays when in the preview when device is rotated. I now can use OrientationEventListener() to figure out the orientation of the device and perform proper image rotation when saving the picture.

I have several buttons on the screen that, when in the portrait mode (0 degree orientation), they are located at the bottom of the screen. When I rotate the device, I now need to redraw the buttons at the new bottom, since the device no longer does this on its own (due to portrait mode forcing). I was thinking of having 4 layouts for this fragment and depending on the orientation, as detected by the OrientationEventListener(), would inflate the correct one. The inflation happens in the onCreateView() for the fragment, how do I now force execution of the onCreateView()?

Or are there better solutions to this or a specific reason to NOT do this in the first place?

Here is the fragment xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".PhotoCaptureFragment" >   

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />   

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/camera_folder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_collection"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_collection" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/camera_capture"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/camera_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/camera_icon" />
```

Thank You,
Gary

Comment: Put your xml file here . You don't need to recreate view .

Comment: @keshav I posted the fragment xml code, the issue is that since I disabled the device from performing its normal portrait/landscape rotation work, I need to change the button locations myself. When the portrait/landscape rotation is performed by the device, everything works, but there is a noticeable pause when switch from one orientation to the other.